# Counting the same word that a user enters from a form with Mysql and PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if some one enters a word into a database from a php form how can you count how many people have entered that same word in the database as well as how not to create a whole unique id for that same word just a count for that same word when the user enters the same word.

Comment: Smart a** I'm not in grammar school ........................,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,???????????????????/ are you happy now? lol

Comment: Don't act childish. If you want help, you should also help us to understand the question. Believe me, it is much much easier then.

Comment: I'm just responding don't want nothing don't say nothing. lol you can give but you can't take it :(

Answer (score 1):

You can create the table wordsCount with the following schema.

```
id | word | count
------------------
1  | word1 | 15
2  | word2 | 8
etc.
```

When someone types the word you can check if the word is already in the table and insert ot update counter. In MySQL can use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). Like this:

```
INSERT INTO table (word,count) VALUES ('word3',1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1;
```

It is better than checking if word exists using

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE word = 'word3'
```

and then deciding if to use INSERT or UPDATE. Of course you have to put UNIQUE KEY on the word column.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work, assuming your `words` table has `word` as a string and `count` as an integer. u may need to modify it depending on how u are interacting with mysql

```
$word = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['word']);
$query = 'UPDATE words SET count = count+1 WHERE word = '.$word;
mysql_query($query);
if( !mysql_affected_rows() ) {
  $query = 'INSERT INTO words (word,count) VALUES('.$word.',1)';
  mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: you could also do 'SELECT id FROM words WHERE word = '.$word and then if it returns an id you do an update otherwise you do an insert. 

but that's more lines and the only time you should ever want _more_ lines is Saturday Night

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return a result set displaying the number of occurences of each value in the "Value" column of the "Data" table. Add a "WHERE" clause if you're only interested in one particular "Value".

```
SELECT Value, COUNT( DISTINCT Id ) AS Occurrences 
FROM Data
GROUP BY Value
```